# Input typography using quantifiers such as `ForAll`

Tags: forall

Whenever possible I prefer to express inputs in mathematical notation (rather than text commands) as I feel this helps one think like a *mathematician*, leaving the calculations to *Mathematica* "in the background."  (Of course not all functions can be expressed in mathematical notation, such as `Reduce` or `FullSimplify`, and so on.)

Thus I use ESC for typesetting integrals and such, or use the ***Basic Math*** palette.

Consider this code:

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, a x^2 + a x - 4 < 0]]
```

(* $-16 < a \leq 0$ *)

The symbol $\forall$ in the *Mathematica* palette *seems* to be appropriate to replace `ForAll`, but doesn't work:

```
Resolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ForAll]\), \(x\)]\([a\ x^2\  + \ a\ x - 4 < 0]\)\)]
```

I've tried a number of variations, without success.

How can one express a function call, such as above, using the $\forall$ symbol?

Comment: `\[ForAll]`  seems work.

Comment: @cvgmt:  That certainly typesets the symbol, but when I use that in the full input function call it sets the symbol but doesn't support the desired computation.  (v. 11.3). What am I missing?

Comment: `\[ForAll]` then use  Ctrl _  to put the lower  `x` and then another expression.

Comment: I apologize if I'm missing something basic, but can you typeset the `\[ForAll]` and actually get my sample code (involving `Reduce` and such) to work?  Actually compute the desired answer?  I can't!

Comment: `Resolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ForAll]\), \(x\)]\(a\ x^2\  + \ a\ x - 4 < 0\)\)]`

Comment: Gosh... yes... thanks.  That's *almost* what I had above.  Anyway... thanks again!  My error:  including the `[ ]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An animation maybe useful for such input.

[image]

Comment: Above and beyond the call of duty!  Thanks!  ($+1, \checkmark$). My personal preference is to use **ESC**... but no matter.