# Using the mathematical typography of formal logic

Tags: theorem-proving, forall

As asked in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272235/input-typography-using-quantifiers-such-as-forall), I strongly prefer to use "mathematical" typography in *Mathematica* over text-based ("computer science") typography.  Nevertheless, it sometimes fails for no reason I can discern.

Here's a text-based proof from formal logic:

```
basicAxioms = {ForAll[{a, b}, And[a, b] == And[b, a]],
   ForAll[{a, b}, Or[a, b] == Or[b, a]]};

mybasicProof = FindEquationalProof[And[a, b] == And[b, a], basicAxioms]
```

which yields a perfectly normal proof, as can be seen by

```
mybasicProof["ProofGraph"]
```

But the (apparently) equivalent set of axioms and proof, expressed in mathematical typography, fails:

```
basicAxioms2 = {
   \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ForAll]\), \(\({a, b}\)\(\ \)\)]a\) \[And] 
    b == b \[And] a,
   \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ForAll]\), \(\({a, b}\)\(\ \)\)]a\) \[Or] 
    b == b \[Or] a};

 FindEquationalProof[a \[And] b == b \[And] a, basicAxioms2]
```

How can I express the axioms and proof using mathematical typography, and not `ForAll[]`, `And[]`, `Or[]`, and such text-based entry?

Comment: It's a precedence issue. Equal has higher precedence than And, so `a \[And] b == c` is parsed as `And[a, b==c]` and not `Equal[And[a, b], c]`.

Comment: Up to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TraditionalFormReferenceInformation.html), "Therefore, while StandardForm is an input format and an output format, TraditionalForm is primarily intended as an output format". I think no chance.

Comment: I'd like to add that `mybasicProof["ProofNotebook"]` does not work the job.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @CarlWoll in the comments, it comes down to the precedence of operators.

```
Precedence[And]
(* 215 *)

Precedence[Equal]
(* 290 *)

a ∧ b == b ∧ a // Trace
(* {a && b == b && a, {b == b, True}, a && a} *)
```

Working upon [@CarlWoll's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199836/75628), you can define some other infix equal-like operator, define it as `Equal`, and give it a very low precedence (like the one of [`Equivalent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equivalent.html)) to achieve the desired parsing.

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "eq"}] = 
  TemplateBox[{}, "Equal", DisplayFunction -> (" ⪮ " &), 
   InterpretationFunction :> (Sequence["~", "Equal", "~"] &), 
   SyntaxForm -> "⧦"];
```

[image: eq]

However, the precedence of `ForAll` is $240$, even higher than that of `And`. So you will still need some brackets.

[image: Solution 1]

Obviously, the simplest solution is to just properly parenthesize the whole expression in the first place.

[image: Solution 2]

Comment: Unfortunately, I see `&&` and `==` in `ProofObject`. What does `"ProofNotebook"` produce? Can you present the end of your code as  a code instead of a picture?

Comment: @user64494, I don't really understand where the problem is. My output is [the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHHen.png) as the one the OP wants.

Comment: I have doubts whether  your words do correspond to reality in view of `a&&b==b&&a` in `ProofObject`. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @user64494, sorry, I have read read your comment several times, but I do not understand your point :-/